# Advice Needed on Python Exception Handling

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to add exception handling to the cost and company variables.
I need an exception to make sure my cost variable is greater than $0.
And an exception on the company variable so the input is not empty. The exception on the company variable works but I am having trouble figuring out how to separate the if-else statement. I am still very new to programming.

```
def main():
    print("This program will calculate the shipping cost based on "
          "the total purchase price,\n")

    while True:
        try:
            company = input('Please enter the company name: ')
            if company == "":
                raise ValueError("Please provide a valid company name.")
            break
        except ValueError as excpt:
            print(excpt)

    while True:
        try:
            cost = float(input("Please enter in the purchase price: "))
            if cost <= 0:
                raise ValueError("Please enter a value greater than $0.00.")
            break
        except ValueError as excpt:
            print(excpt)


        if cost <= 100.00:
            shipping = 10.0
        elif cost <= 300.00:
            shipping = 8.0
        elif cost <= 500.00:
            shipping = 5.0
        else:
            shipping = 0.0

        total = cost + shipping

        print("At a purchase price of ${:.2f}, the shipping cost will be ${:.2f},"
                  " with a final total of ${:.2f}.".format(cost, shipping, total))
        print('{}, thank you for shopping with us!'.format(company))

main()
```

This is the output:

```
Please enter the company name: 
Please provide a valid company name.
Please enter the company name: ASX
Please enter in the purchase price: -5.99
Please enter a value greater than $0.00.
At a purchase price of $-5.99, the shipping cost will be $10.00, with a final total of $4.01.
ASX, thank you for shopping with us!
Please enter in the purchase price:
```

Comment: What's your problem though.

Comment: Also, I think you need to fix the indentation. After the second indentation you have your main code. Backspace that chunk and it works properly. Unless you pasted your code on SO incorrectly.

Comment: The program still prints out the negative purchase price instead of asking for it again and then printing out the final statement with the positive value only.

Comment: I need the last line "Please enter the purchase price:" to come before the ending print statement. So the print statement doesn't take a negative value.

Comment: Is this not what your getting.```Please enter in the purchase price: -100
Please enter a value greater than $0.00.```?

Comment: I am but immediately after it prints out "At a purchase price of $-9.00, the shipping cost will be $10.00 with a final total of $1.00." I need the program to wait till the user enters a positive value until the end print statement occors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your second indentation after the second while loop. You are breaking into emptiness.

**newcode**

```
def main(): 
    print("This program will calculate the shipping cost based on " "the total purchase price,\n")

    while True:
        try:
            company = input('Please enter the company name: ')
            if company == "":
                raise ValueError("Please provide a valid company name.")
            break
        except ValueError as excpt:
            print(excpt)
    while True:
        try:
            cost = float(input("Please enter in the purchase price: "))
            if cost <= 0:
                raise ValueError("Please enter a value greater than $0.00.")
            break
        except ValueError as excpt:
            print(excpt)


    if cost <= 100.00:
        shipping = 10.0
    elif cost <= 300.00:
        shipping = 8.0
    elif cost <= 500.00:
        shipping = 5.0
    else:
        shipping = 0.0

    total = cost + shipping

    print("At a purchase price of ${:.2f}, the shipping cost will be ${:.2f},"
            " with a final total of ${:.2f}.".format(cost, shipping, total))
    print('{}, thank you for shopping with us!'.format(company))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output**

```
This program will calculate the shipping cost based on the total purchase price,

Please enter the company name: apple
Please enter in the purchase price: -100
Please enter a value greater than $0.00.
Please enter in the purchase price: 100
At a purchase price of $100.00, the shipping cost will be $10.00, with a final total of $110.00.
apple, thank you for shopping with us!
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
# error handling made by yourself

class NoCompanyName(Exception):
    pass
class CostError(Exception):
    pass
# new code
def main_new():
    from time import sleep
    print("This program will calculate the shipping cost based on \" the totalprice\"\n")
    while True:
        company = input("Please enter company name.\n")
        if company == None:
            raise NoCompanyName("Please enter company name!")
        else:
            pass
        while True:
            cost = int(input("Please enter purchase price."))
            if cost == None:
                raise CostError("You should  specify cost that wasn\'t lower than 0 or None!")
            else:
                if cost <= 0:
                    raise CostError("You should specify cost that wasn\'t lower than 0!")
                else:
                    pass
            if cost <= 100.00:
                     shipping = 10.0
            elif cost <= 300.00:
                     shipping = 8.0
            elif cost <= 500.00:
                    shipping = 5.0
            else:
                     shipping = 0.0
            total = cost + shipping
            print(f"At purchase price of ${cost}, the shipping will cost ${shipping}. With final total is ${total}")
            print(f"{company}, Thank you for shipping with us!")
            sleep(5)
main_new()
```

Answer (score 0):

use `assert` statement instead then catch `AssertionError` instead of `ValueError`, here is how it will look like:

```
try:
    cost = float(input())
    assert cost > 0, "Cost must be greater than 0"
except AssertionError as e:
    print(e)
```

and do the same with other inputs